# jade: escape included file contents

Tags: javascript, pug

I see in the [jade docs](http://jade-lang.com/reference/includes/) that I can include an external file and run it through a filter.
If there's no filter and no filter-associated extension,the file just renders as is.

**escape.txt**

```
escape <span>this</span>
```

**index.html**

```
include escape.txt
include:markdown escape.txt
```

renders:

```
escape <span>this</span>
<p>escape <span>this</span></p>
```

How can I pass the included file through the escape filter?

Ideally:

```
include:escape escape.txt
```

or:

```
- var fileinc = include escape.txt
= fileinc
```

would render:

```
escape &lt;span&gt;this&lt;/span&gt;
```

I understand I can manually add a new filter during runtime, however I think this might be too complicated since I'm using this during Gulp preprocessing and not on nodejs server.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've found the use of [transformers](https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/transformers) to be extremely straightforward in this situation.
There are individual libraries for each transformer under [JSTransformers](https://github.com/jstransformers), and Jade recognizes them once they're installed.

So in this case:

```
$ npm install jstransformer-escape-html

escape.txt:
escape <span>this</span>

index.jade:
include:escape-html escape.txt

$ jade index.jade
//=> index.html
index.html:
escape &lt;span&gt;this&lt;/span&gt;
```